# eclipse cannot be opened after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: eclipse, windows-10

After I update my PC from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10, my Eclipse Java SE IDE and EE IDE cannot be opened anymore. I tried to set it to Windows 8 compatible but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to fix it are as following:

1. I downloaded the latest version of Eclipse and extract it.
2. Rename the previous one (e.g., rename c://program files/eclipse to c://program files/eclipse_old
3. Cope new Eclipse to the previous directory (e.g., c://program files/eclipse)

Then, the Eclipse can be run again. Be careful to select the right version of eclipse (32bit vs. 64bit).